# How can I send the same Twitter message multiple times?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I am trying to add the iOS 5 Twitter API to my app, and Twitter is giving me crap about sending the same direct message a second time.

> ```
> Twitter response, HTTP response: 403
> Response Data
> {"error":"There was an error sending your message: Whoops! You already said that.","request":"\/1\/direct_messages\/new.json"}
> ```

Is there anyway to get around this so I can test my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try sending a random message or the (stringified) time? It would be unique an each occasion, and it wouldn't require you to hack/work around/otherwise violate Twitter's this restirction.

Comment: I think I might have no other choice.

Comment: I guess this is the only solution.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying! :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can tweet the same message multiple times if the text is never exactly the same.
For example, [1001tweets](http://www.1001tweets.com/) helps you to post multiples times some of your tweets. To do that, it keeps only the tweets containing a link and changes it using an URL shortener.